# Optimal variable-time logging of a real-time data stream

Tags: data, logging, statistics, information-theory

[Cross-posted from stats stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608326/optimal-variable-time-sampling-of-a-real-time-data-stream)

Say I have a logging utility in my application that I use for recording timestamped diagnostic log messages. I want to add tracking of some performance metrics to this log. Moreover, I want to do this intelligently, so as not to explode the size of the log files.

A convenient way to do a form of lossy compression would be to only record values when it appears that something "interesting" is happening - as judged, for example, by looking at the output of a high-pass filter applied to the value.

It's clear that the success of such an implementation depends critically on the design of the filter. How can we design an optimal filter (in a rate-distortion sense), given some knowledge (e.g. moment structure) of the stream we are trying to compress?

Comment: Maybe try asking in Signal Processing stack exchange.

Comment: [Cross-posting questions is not accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) by our community, as long as you cannot tailor the question to the specific topic area of the different sites (which in this case you clearly did not). Posting the link to the cross-post does not change this. I think the suggestion from the former comment is a good idea, but you should delete your two other posts (here and on cross-validated) **before** you post there.

Comment: ... said that, regardless where you post your question, it is barely missing an example - "performance metrics" is a very vague term and mean a lot of different things for different types of application. Hence I am voting to close ("needs details or clarity").

Comment: From a semantic perspective, sure, it's vague.  From a practical perspective, it's not vague at all - numbers in memory are numbers in memory.

I've cross-posted on other stackexchange sites before and no one has ever complained except for here; if you want to close the question you can, but personally I really don't see what the disservice to the community is by allowing a cross-paradigm question to be seen on multiple mostly non-overlapping sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide how much memory your filter is allowed to consume. This is what you have to work with when deciding if something is interesting enough to send to the file. In here you can hold more than you send to the file. You just can't hold it for long because new stuff is coming in and you need somewhere to put it.

Not saving the stream limits the algorithms you can use. Batch ones that use a multiple pass approach can’t be used because they need data that’s gone.

But there are single pass ones that can work on a stream to calculate on the fly such as the [The Welford’s algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-real-time-and-unsupervised-anomalies-in-streaming-data-a-starting-point-760a4bacbdf8) that lets you calculate variance and standard deviation. Identify metrics worth maintaining and you can trigger logging when you see anomalous outliers.

Comment: This was the approach I was planning to take; what I'm stuck on is how to pick *what to do with the stuff in the buffer.*  There has to be some well-studied methodology here...

Comment: @user3716267 there are many. But aside from dupe counting or random sampling they all expect to know more about the data stream then you’ve told us.

Comment: I get that; I'm not looking for a particular solution here, but rather an executive summary (ideally references) for what the problem framing typically looks like so that I can attempt to do the math myself.  It feels like a rate-distortion-theory problem, and I can't imagine it hasn't been studied; I'd imagine there would be a spectrum of approaches ranging from "highly-parametric" to "nonparametric" depending on how much we actually know about the data stream, but I'm having a hard time finding a clear conceptual overview.

Comment: @user3716267 better now?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the currently in vogue approach is to do the opposite.

Instead of logging what you need for your reports, log everything and then build your reports and calculate metrics.

The logic is that if you filter out the "not interesting" but then think of a report which needs that data, you are all out of luck.

Comment: Ewan, we do live in the age of massive hard drives. But there are still use cases where you don't want save the entire data stream raw. And I can still fill up any hard drive with one line of code.

Comment: This is a valid approach, but it places a lot more technical burden on the logging implementation.  If log size can be managed by some simple application logic (e.g. a high-pass filter based on a buffer, as @candied_orange mentioned), that is potentially way less-disruptive to the rest of a codebase.

Comment: one could argue that its exactly the same technical burden. you filter out the data you don't want, either by using the cpu on your application or the cpu on your reporting server. Sure there are limits to the amount of data you can send over a wire, and maybe there are some thing you just never need to log. But does it really make sense to run a complex filter in your application rather than on a dedicated reporting box?

Comment: Not all technical burden is computational cost.  There is also *engineering cost.*  A high-pass filter is not a complicated piece of code (a first-order high-pass filter is just a finite difference), and the desire here is to get a "quick and good-enough" solution rather than to invest in something substantial that would disrupt the existing logging implementation.  Logs here are stored locally rather than recorded remotely, so we can't just compress them on ingestion.